# How to resolve AWS Elastic Beanstalk Django health check problems

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

I've recently deployed my Django API backend to AWS EB to their Linux 2 system (exact platform name is `Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2`).

Almost everything is working as expected, but my application health status is `Severe` and after hours of debugging I've no idea why.

The application's health check is being handled using the following endpoint (`django-health-check` module).

```
url(r'^ht/', include('health_check.urls'))
```

100% of the requests have a status code of `200` but my overall health status is the following:

```
|--------------------|----------------|---------------------------------------------------|
|   instance-id      |   status       |   cause                                           |
|--------------------|----------------|---------------------------------------------------|
|   Overall          |   Degraded     |   Impaired services on all instances.             |
|   i-0eb89f...      |   Severe       |   Following services are not running: release.    |
|--------------------|----------------|---------------------------------------------------|
```

The strangest thing is the fact that the message `Following services are not running: release.` is unique to the internet (seems like no one has had such problem before).

The other weird thing are the contents of my `/var/log/healthd/daemon.log` file which are lines similar to

```
W, [2020-07-21T09:00:01.209091 #3467]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2020-07-21-09" does not exist
```

where the time changes.

The last thing that may be relevant are the contents of my single file inside `.ebextensions` directory:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "app.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: app.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
    /static_files: static_files
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql-devel: []
```

Does anyone have any idea how can this be resolved? The ultimate goal is to have the green OK health.

---

**EDIT:** In the end I switched to the `Basic` health system and the problems suddenly went away. I am however still interested in solving the original problem as the `Enhanced` health system provides some benefits

Comment: Is it load-balanced environment?

Comment: @Marcin Yes it is, I also forgot to mention that I am making use of `Enhanced health reporting and monitoring`

Comment: The application works exactly as expected? Logs such as /var/log/cloud-init-cmd don't show any errors?

Comment: @Marcin I meant that endpoints as well as database are all working just fine. I downloaded full logs from EB console and went through them. All I found were 2 errors from eb-engine.log that didn't seem relevant (`[ERROR] nginx: the configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful` and `[ERROR] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/worker.service to /etc/systemd/system/worker.service.`). A file called `cloud-init-cmd` isn't even part of the logs.

Comment: @Marcin I also switched to `Basic` health system (instead of `Enhanced`) and the problems disappeared. I'm however still interested in solving the original problem.

Comment: The file should be `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`, sorry.

Comment: @Marcin No, the file doesn't contain a single error

Comment: Don't know why you got errors. Basic health reporting is only based on LB an EC2 health checks. Enhanced also monitors your logs and other metrics from the inside of the instances. Thus maybe it was finding some errors there, and reporting them as health issues.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the problem you have maybe due to the ALLOWED_HOSTS settings located in your file settings.py.

EB sends an HTTP request to your application to see if its working but Django blocks any communication that is not from the specified hosts in the setting variable. But there is a problem here, EB sends the request to the private ip of the ec2 instance.

The easiest way to solve this is to allow all HOSTS like this inside your `settings.py` file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
```

This may lead to security issues but is the fastest way to do it. Now, to make it work dynamically, since ec2 instances can be spin-up at any time the private ip change from instance to instance.

To solve this you have to get the private IP at the beginning of the deployment process.

At the top of your `settings.py` place the following functions:

```
import os
import requests
# Other imports ...

def is_ec2_linux():
"""Detect if we are running on an EC2 Linux Instance
   See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/identify_ec2_instances.html
"""
    if os.path.isfile("/sys/hypervisor/uuid"):
        with open("/sys/hypervisor/uuid") as f:
            uuid = f.read()
            return uuid.startswith("ec2")
    return False

def get_token():
"""Set the autorization token to live for 6 hours (maximum)"""
    headers = {
        'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds': '21600',
    }
    response = requests.put('http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token', headers=headers)
    return response.text


def get_linux_ec2_private_ip():
    """Get the private IP Address of the machine if running on an EC2 linux server.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html"""

    if not is_ec2_linux():
        return None
    try:
        token = get_token()
        headers = {
            'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token': f"{token}",
        }
        response = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', headers=headers)
        return response.text
    except:
        return None
    finally:
        if response:
            response.close()
# Other settings
```

The most important functions are `get_token()` and `get_linux_ec2_private_ip()`, the first one sets the access token and retrieves it for the second one to use it and get the current ec2 instance IP.

Once you have retrieved it, add it to your ALLOWED_HOSTS

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'mywebsite.com']
private_ip = get_linux_ec2_private_ip()
if private_ip:
   ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(private_ip)
```

After that just commit your changes and redeploy it with `eb deploy` if you have set the EB CLI.

Comment: What's that hardcoded ip `169.254.169.254` ?

Comment: It seems to be a special reserved IP address. In AWS EC2 it is used to distribute metadata between instances. You can take a look at it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a package `django-ebhealthcheck` that's designed to solve this problem by getting the local ip of your ec2 instance and adding it to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, it's very simple to use, you just have to add `'ebhealthcheck.apps.EBHealthCheckConfig'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Package github page – https://github.com/sjkingo/django-ebhealthcheck