# Django Rest - Create and Action method returns error 403 forbidden

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I built a simple Django/React app that allows users to post short texts that can be liked and unliked. In the console I get, POST http://localhost:8000/api/posts/create/ 403 (Forbidden) and POST http://localhost:8000/api/posts/create/ 403 (Forbidden).

The REST Framework Renderer gives me,

> ```
> GET /api/posts/create/
> HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
> Allow: POST, OPTIONS
> Content-Type: application/json
> Vary: Accept
>
> {
>     "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
> }
> ```

and,

> ```
> GET /api/posts/action/
> HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
> Allow: OPTIONS, POST
> Content-Type: application/json
> Vary: Accept
>
> {
>     "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
> }
> ```

The console gives me, **xhr.send(jsonData)** in the components as error. At first I thought it was a simple authentication error but I tried signing in to admin on different browsers to no success.

What am I missing here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

webapp/webapp-web/src/lookup/components.js

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

export function backendLookup(method, endpoint, callback, data) {
  let jsonData;
  if (data){
    jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
  }
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  const url = `http://localhost:8000/api${endpoint}`
  xhr.responseType = "json"
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  xhr.open(method, url)
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

  if (csrftoken){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
  }
  
  xhr.onload = function() {
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    callback({"message": "The request was an error"}, 400)
  }
  xhr.send(jsonData)
}
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    post_action_view,
    post_delete_view,
    post_detail_view, 
    post_list_view,
    post_create_view,
)
'''
CLIENT
Base ENDPOINT /api/tweets/
'''
urlpatterns = [
    path('', post_list_view),
    path('action/', post_action_view),
    path('create/', post_create_view),
    path('<int:post_id>/', post_detail_view),
    path('<int:post_id>/delete/', post_delete_view),
]
```

webapp/urls.py

```
"""tweetme2 URL Configuration
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include # url()
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from app.views import (
    posts_list_view,
    posts_detail_view,
    posts_profile_view,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', posts_list_view),
    path('<int:tweet_id>', posts_detail_view),
    path('profile/<str:username>', posts_profile_view),
    path('api/posts/', include('app.api.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
                document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

api/views.py

```
import random
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url

from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from ..forms import PostForm
from ..models import Post
from ..serializers import (
    PostSerializer,
    PostActionSerializer,
    PostCreateSerializer
)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS

@api_view(['POST'])
# @authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response({}, status=400)

@api_view(['GET'])
def post_detail_view(request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Post.objects.filter(id=post_id)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({}, status=404)
    obj = qs.first()
    serializer = PostSerializer(obj)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

@api_view(['DELETE', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_delete_view(request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Post.objects.filter(id=post_id)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({}, status=404)
    qs = qs.filter(user=request.user)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({"message": "You cannot delete this Post"}, status=401)
    obj = qs.first()
    obj.delete()
    return Response({"message": "Post deleted"}, status=200)

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_action_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = PostActionSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        data = serializer.validated_data
        post_id = data.get("id")
        action = data.get("action")
        qs = Post.objects.filter(id=post_id)
        if not qs.exists():
            return Response({}, status=404)
        obj = qs.first()
        if action == "like":
            obj.likes.add(request.user)
            serializer = PostSerializer(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
        elif action == "unlike":
            obj.likes.remove(request.user)
            serializer = PostSerializer(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response({}, status=200)

@api_view(['GET'])
def post_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    username = request.GET.get("username")
    if username != None:
        qs = qs.filter(user__username__iexact=username)
    serializer = PostSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

webapp/views.py

```
import random
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url


ALLOWED_HOSTS = settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
    return render(request, "pages/home.html", context={"username": username}, status=200)

def posts_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "pictures/list.html")

def posts_detail_view(request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "pictures/detail.html", context={"post_id": post_id})

def posts_profile_view(request, username, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "pictures/profile.html", context={"profile_username": username})
```

webapp/serializers.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post

MAX_TWEET_LENGTH = settings.MAX_TWEET_LENGTH
POST_ACTION_OPTIONS = settings.POST_ACTION_OPTIONS

class PostActionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    action = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_action(self, value):
        value = value.lower().strip()
        if not value in POST_ACTION_OPTIONS:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a valid action")
        return value

class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["id", "content", "likes"]
    def get_likes(self, obj):
        return obj.likes.count()
        
    def validate_content(self, value): 
        if len(value) > MAX_TWEET_LENGTH:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This description is too long")
        return value

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    content = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["id", "content", "likes"]
    
    def get_likes(self, obj):
        return obj.likes.count()

    def get_content(self, obj):
        return obj.content
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for webapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'g7nkjipd$4$n=r8*8c(ct$wf!qg$-hb$wn6_*f$#8j*j7!doge'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "localhost"]
LOGIN_URL = "/login"

MAX_TWEET_LENGTH = 240
POST_ACTION_OPTIONS = ["like", "unlike"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third-party
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    # internal
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR / "static-root",)

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/.*$'

DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES = [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ]

DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES = [
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
]
if DEBUG:
    DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES += [
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
    #DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES += [
    #    'webapp.rest_api.dev.DevAuthentication'
    #]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
}
```

[Chrome Network tab][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOQA8.png

Comment: Is error 403 Forbidden or 405 Method Not Allowed? Or both? And which you want to solve, if both?

Comment: I am trying to solve both, but I feel completely lost. Action and Create both works through http://localhost:8000/admin so I am guessing that the error appears on the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

I believe **CSRF** is causing the error, check if your DRF setting is using basic auth or token auth.

Comment: I added my settings.py file in at the end, mind taking a look at it? @CarlosSaldana

Comment: DRF is using basic auth

Comment: add 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication' to DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES:

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in the urls.py file, where the ViewSet classes was in the wrong order:

```
...
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', VehicleViewSet , basename='VehicleViewSet')
router.register(r'transference', TransferenceViewSet , basename='TransferenceViewSet')
...
```

Django was testing first if the url match the '', and this always return a successful match, causing my project to respond the request with the wrong ViewSet that has a different Permission class.

The solution was just to put the more specific routes first, ending up like this:

```
...
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'transference', TransferenceViewSet , basename='TransferenceViewSet')
router.register(r'', VehicleViewSet , basename='VehicleViewSet')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You including `action` and `create` suburl into `api/posts/` url (`webapp/urls.py`)
2. Your `action/` path function is `post_action_view` and `create` is `post_create_view` (`api/urls.py`)
3. You set decorators `@api_view(['POST'])` before `post_action_view` and `post_create_view` (`api/views.py`)
4. You have get error `"Method \"GET\" not allowed."`

So... do you see any logic here?

Set `@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])` if you want to allow both methods.
In other way, set `'POST'` method when you running JS's `xhr.open(method, url)`, not `'GET'`.

**EDIT1:**

[SAME PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696380/aws-elastic-beanstalk-django-application-health-check-problem/64697157#64697157)

Comment: Still cant get it to work. What exactly should I change? @rzlvmp

Comment: Okay, I thought that your problem is 405 status code. But 405 is a correct behavior and not related to 403. Looks like 403 appears because you non authenticated. Here is no details how you trying to login. And are you logged in at all?

Comment: I am logged in through the adminpanel

Comment: I added an image to the end of my post showing what the Chrome Network debugger gave me.

Comment: Ok. Try to comment out @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated]) in both functions (disable authentication) and check response code. Is it will be 403? That will be hint.

Comment: It still displays 403. So I guess that means that the issue is not with Auth? What else could it be?

Comment: Oh... Got it. I added link in my answer. Please, provide django logs next time